# How to equally distribute the curve profile

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a data frame with rpm values and efficiency values. RPM curve values are not equally distributed, and the RPM values are irregular intervals. How can I make the RPM values occur at regular intervals? Here is my data and Python code:

```py
dict ={'rpm': [363, 362, 361, 360, 359, 358, 357, 356, 357, 354, 357, 356, 354, 351, 350, 349, 348, 347, 346, 345, 344, 342, 340, 339, 338, 337, 334, 332, 330, 329, 327, 325, 324, 321, 319, 317, 316, 313, 310, 308, 299, 288, 275, 265, 256, 247, 239, 230, 220, 209, 207, 200, 191, 182, 172, 164, 156, 148, 141, 135, 128, 121, 111, 110, 91, 98, 87, 74, 79, 76, 68, 50, 51, 50, 51, 41, 24, 0], 'eff': [30.0, 44.7, 55.0, 65.5, 71.85, 75.8, 79.05, 82.25, 81.0, 87.7, 85.8, 87.2, 87.0, 89.0, 88.2, 88.4, 89.0, 90.8, 89.6, 89.3, 89.6, 89.56666666666668, 89.8, 87.9, 89.2, 90.7, 88.0, 88.3, 88.6, 89.4, 87.2, 86.7, 85.6, 85.4, 85.3, 85.4, 85.1, 86.0, 84.5, 83.8, 82.9, 81.8, 80.7, 79.6, 78.8, 77.8, 77.0, 75.9, 74.7, 73.5, 73.2, 72.2, 70.6, 69.1, 67.4, 65.9, 64.2, 62.4, 60.7, 59.1, 57.2, 55.5, 52.0, 51.8, 44.6, 48.1, 43.8, 39.0, 41.4, 40.3, 36.8, 28.4, 29.1, 28.1, 28.9, 23.7, 1.6, 0.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

[image]
in rpm columns the difference between every two adjacent values is sometime 1 sometimes 0 sometimes more than 1 how to make them equally distributed so that difference between any two adjacent values is 2 something the rpm values has to be 363,360,357,354,............,9,6,3 and I want to get to know for every rpm value what is the efficiency how to do it I used interpolation but the curve points are not equally distributed kindly help me through it thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you can fit the data with a smoothing spline, since you probably don't want all the spikes. Before you can do that, you need to make the x data (`"rpm"`) strictly monotonic (i.e. strictly increasing without duplicates). To do this,

1. Sort the data by `"rpm"`.
2. Deal with the duplicates. For my code, I just dropped duplicates, but you should do something more responsible than that.

With that "cleaned" data, you can use [`scipy.interpolate.makes_smoothing_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline), which can then be evaluated at the desired `"rpm"` points. I left the default smoothing, but you can increase the smoothing by passing the `lam` argument a value greater than or equal to 0 (if you do, you might want to set it to at least 100 for this problem).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_smoothing_spline
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

# don't call this "dict" since that's a python keyword
data = {"rpm": [363, 362, 361, 360, 359, 358, 357, 356, 357, 354, 357, 356, 
                354, 351, 350, 349, 348, 347, 346, 345, 344, 342, 340, 339, 
                338, 337, 334, 332, 330, 329, 327, 325, 324, 321, 319, 317, 
                316, 313, 310, 308, 299, 288, 275, 265, 256, 247, 239, 230, 
                220, 209, 207, 200, 191, 182, 172, 164, 156, 148, 141, 135, 
                128, 121, 111, 110, 91, 98, 87, 74, 79, 76, 68, 50, 51, 50, 
                51, 41, 24, 0], 
        "eff": [30.0, 44.7, 55.0, 65.5, 71.85, 75.8, 79.05, 82.25, 81.0, 87.7, 
                85.8, 87.2, 87.0, 89.0, 88.2, 88.4, 89.0, 90.8, 89.6, 89.3, 
                89.6, 89.56666666666668, 89.8, 87.9, 89.2, 90.7, 88.0, 88.3, 
                88.6, 89.4, 87.2, 86.7, 85.6, 85.4, 85.3, 85.4, 85.1, 86.0, 
                84.5, 83.8, 82.9, 81.8, 80.7, 79.6, 78.8, 77.8, 77.0, 75.9, 
                74.7, 73.5, 73.2, 72.2, 70.6, 69.1, 67.4, 65.9, 64.2, 62.4, 
                60.7, 59.1, 57.2, 55.5, 52.0, 51.8, 44.6, 48.1, 43.8, 39.0, 
                41.4, 40.3, 36.8, 28.4, 29.1, 28.1, 28.9, 23.7, 1.6, 0.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sort_values(by="rpm", inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset="rpm", inplace=True)


spl = make_smoothing_spline(df.rpm, df.eff, lam=None)

rpm_smooth = np.arange(df.rpm.min(), df.rpm.max(), 3)
eff_smooth = spl(rpm_smooth)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.rpm, df.eff, ".")
ax.plot(rpm_smooth, eff_smooth)
ax.set_xlabel("RPM")
ax.set_ylabel("Efficiency")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the way to go is an interpolation :

```
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(df["rpm"],df["eff"])
rpm_interp=np.linspace(0,363,1000)
#this gives you 1000 equally spaced points between 0 and 363
#you can get your values spaced out by 3 by replacing 1000 with 363//3 + 1
eff_interp=f(rpm_interp)
plt.plot(rpm_interp,eff_interp)
```

Which gives you this when you plot efficiency as a function of RPM : [image]

Comment: i updated my graph like that i want to get the two curves are in y axis and requally sample the rpm curve

Comment: maybe do : plt.plot(rpm_interp)
plt.plot(eff_interp)